# How do I get rid of this MATLAB error? "In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

Tags: matlab, struct, indexing

I keep getting this error for the b array below

A = ones(numTrials, 2*numDOFs);
b = ones(numTrials, 1);

```
k = 2;
for i = 2:numSubjects
    for j = 1:numTrials
        A(k,:) = cat(2,subject(i).trial(j).torque_integral, subject(i).trial(j).work_integral); 
        b(k) = [subject(i).trial(j).E - subject(i).trial(j).B - sum(subject(i).trial(j).work_integral)];        
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
```

---

I tested each component of the creation of the b array (subject(i).trial(j).E, etc.) and they are all scalar values.  So I should be able to add/subtract them then assign them to an index in the preallocated b array.  A simple dummy version would look like this:

> > c = ones(4,1)

c =

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

> > c(3) = 3

c =

```
 1
 1
 3
 1
```

---

So what am I missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: thanks! i had a non-obvious error somewhere farther up in the code, and this error message disappeared when i fixed it.  interesting alternative answer, i haven't explored cells yet, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably print out the size of every element that goes into the assignments, and your problem will solve itself;

```
size(cat(2,subject(i).trial(j).torque_integral, subject(i).trial(j).work_integral))
size([subject(i).trial(j).E - subject(i).trial(j).B - sum(subject(i).trial(j).work_integral)])
```

Note - I am leaving off the trailing `;` in the above, which causes the value to be output to the console; also, your assignment to B has `[]` around it, as though you are trying to create a vector. If it's truly a single element there is no need for that...